# How to show files being copied, moved,etc. on installer screen using WIX

Tags: installation, wix

I have my installer and is working fine.

What I want to add more is that I want to show the work done by installer on installer screen (Example, installing Microsoft SQL Server 2005, we get the files being copied, moved, registry entry created,......)

Similarly I want to show this on my installer.

So can anyone help me on this to how to show all these at runtime on installer screen.

Thanks,
Sunil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copying my answer to the same question on wix-users list:

Use [ProgressText](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_progresstext.htm) element.

The 'Template' attribute is the place to put tokens to reflect the progress. See the standard [InstallFiles action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369503(VS.85).aspx) for example.
The table "ActionData messages" lists the possible tokens for this action.

Sample:

```
<ProgressText Action="InstallFiles" Template="File: [9][1]">!(loc.InstallFilesActionText)</ProgressText>
```

Outputs:

```
   File: C:\Program Files\MyApp\bin\my.dll
```

etc.

Hope this helps,

Comment: I tried this but it was not working for me.                        This code is formatting the way the file names are written on the log file but the file name are not displaying on the installer screen

Comment: @Olive, probably, your control is not subscribed to the ActionData event - in this case it won't display anything, even if you author ProgressText elements...

Comment: I am getting error
`The localization variable !(loc.InstallFilesActionText) is unknown.  Please ensure the variable is defined.`

Comment: Now after getting rid of previous message, I am getting new message 
`Error 34 The primary key 'InstallFiles' is duplicated in table 'ActionText'.  Please remove one of the entries or rename a part of the primary key to avoid the collision.`

Comment: That's because it's duplicated somewhere else, probably, in WiX dialog sets. It's just a sample anyway, tweak it to fit your needs

Comment: I searched through whole solution and didnt found any other occurrence. Can it be because i am using `MyWixUI_Mondo`?

Comment: @Yan, I included the code to subscribe the ActionData. Still it is not displaying the Files name...My code is<Control Id="MyProgressBar" Type="ProgressBar" X="35" Y="115" Width="300" Height="10" ProgressBlocks="yes">
          <Subscribe Event="SetProgress" Attribute="Progress" />
        </Control>
        <Control Id="StatusLabel" Type="Text" X="35" Y="100" Width="35" Height="10" Text="$(loc.ProgressDlgStatusLabel)" />
        <Control Id="ActionText" Type="Text" X="70" Y="100" Width="265" Height="10">
          <Subscribe Event="ActionText" Attribute="Text" />
        </Control>

Comment: According to your snippet, you're subscribing to ActionText, not ActionData. See the ProgressDlg from the WiX standard set for the example

Comment: @Yan, Thanks a lot, your comment help me a lot and m finally able to display file names on the progress dialog.