# Wix installation progress

Tags: wix

I would like to know how can I display the file activity during an MSI installation using Wix installer. For example, a lot of installers nowadays have a 'Show details button' that expands a dialog and shows the installation activity like what is being copied, removed, registered, etc. On clicking the button again, the dialog collapses. ANy help or clue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Cheers,
Harish

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643658/how-to-show-files-being-copied-moved-etc-on-installer-screen-using-wix

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to show files being copied, moved,etc. on installer screen using WIX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643658/how-to-show-files-being-copied-moved-etc-on-installer-screen-using-wix)

Comment: But, shouldn't this be going so fast that it isn't useable? And how is it useable anyway? Users who want a log can [create a log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/command-line-options).

Comment: I agree Tom, no offence Harish. This has been one of my pet-peeves in fact. A setup should just get files deployed and not do anything smart at all - NVMe's make deployment quick. You can even shell-open a web browser to access help resources before kicking off the install - so there is something to look at if it takes a while, or better yet do so during application launch - also ensuring that all help material can be maintained at a single location on the server and not bloat the setup and be hard to maintain. Just another rant. Pardon (assume French voice). "Lemoon" (citron).

Answer (score 0):

The informations you want to handle are in the [InstallFiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/installfiles-action?redirectedfrom=MSDN) action.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643658/how-to-show-files-being-copied-moved-etc-on-installer-screen-using-wix?noredirect=1&lq=1) to get a sample.